# configuration failed for package 'ROracle'

Tags: r, installation, package, roracle

I'm trying to install ROracle and I have the following error :

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10) -- "One Push-Up"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

* Project '~/profiler-gas' loaded. [renv 0.15.2]
* The project may be out of sync -- use `renv::status()` for more details.
> install.packages("ROracle")
Retrieving 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ROracle_1.3-1.1.tar.gz' ...
    OK [file is up to date]
Installing ROracle [1.3-1.1] ...
    FAILED
Error installing package 'ROracle':
===================================

* installing to library 'C:/Users/hh6011/Documents/profiler-gas/renv/staging/1'
* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/Users/hh6011/Documents/profiler-gas/renv/staging/1/ROracle'
Error: install of package 'ROracle' failed [error code 1]
```

I already followed the steps described here : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html

(download Basic Package & SDK Package, paste unzipped files in C:\oracle\instantclient_X_X, create variables OCI_INC & OCI_LIB64, add C:\oracle\instantclient_X_X to the PATH and copy C:\oracle\instantclient_X_X\sdk\include\Ociver.h to C:\Program Files\R\R-X.X.X\include)

Comment: You are supposed to search before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package 'ROracle'

You likely need to install Rtools. See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ for more details.